# box-shadow is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

i m currently creating child theme of premiumpress - realtorpress.

well actually i am having trouble with css.

when i am creating a map box and i want to show the shadow insdie of this div.

so i done something like that

```
<div class="map-box">
    <div id="map_homepage"></div>
</div>
```

and the theme is using "Put Me On The Map" jquery API .. which is available at [codecanyon.net](http://codecanyon.net/item/put-me-on-the-map/51284)

so i wrap the css of map-box

```
.map-box {
    width: 610px;
    height: 357px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

but i don't know why the inside shadow is not working ... its not showing .. please somebody help me to solve this issue and tell me why i am causing this issue.

and if you want to check the real source codes you can viste the website where i am working on right now http://goo.gl/zXCnU

thank you

Comment: The shadow is actually *under* the map (visible only when the map is loading).

Comment: workaround: put a div over the whole thing and give that the box-shadow. `<div class="map-box" style="position:absolute; top: 0; z-index: 1000;"></div><div>load content here</div>`

Comment: The shadow is actually visible. But it seems to be invisible due to the surrounding map color. If you set the zoom level to 0, you can clearly visible on the map.

Comment: @19greg96 thank you, its working. but i cause me another issue that now i am unable to move the map location. do you have any other solution for this.??

Comment: Hmm.. the problem here is that your shadow div is getting all the events that your map is supposed to get. I don't think there is a workaround for this unless google provides a way to dynamically move the position the map. That way you could capture mousedown and mouse move events and create your own drag handler and send the mouse data to your map.

Comment: @19greg96 this can be a very long way to do this thing..

Comment: You might also make 4 shadow pngs and place them over the map so they only cover 10px of it on all the sides.

Comment: yes this can be a good idea.. offcourse i should try this. so now my task is to create 4 shadow pngs and put them in 4 div's right, left, top and bottom and use absolute position to fit them above the corners of the map ..

Answer (score 3):

The shadow is showing - the Google maps code places the map over the top of it.

You might try playing around with the z-index of your box (or the map) to get it to float over the top of the map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some padding for the shadow to show: https://img.skitch.com/20120520-batg116c5eni4h9arp71srreew.jpg

**Edit**: https://img.skitch.com/20120520-cc6dun4ecqrekik51s6pgtut35.jpg

Comment: although, the map doesn't go under the shadow if you do it that way.

Comment: well, i tried that way also but it not working in firefox. i think you are using IE

Comment: hmm , well i tried in firefox and this is not responding as like the image you have provided.

Comment: ok, I wrapped it in another box, put the shadow and the padding on that, and decreased the width of map-box: https://img.skitch.com/20120520-cc6dun4ecqrekik51s6pgtut35.jpg